# how to get an integer value while querying a count query through DataFrame?

Tags: python, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hivecontext

I am writing this code to get the integer value of count in specified table:

```
sc = SparkContext("local", "spar")
hive_context = HiveContext(sc)
hive_context.sql("use zs_trainings_trainings_db")
df = hive_context.sql("select count(*) from ldg_sales")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

```
hive_context.table("sales").count
```

or

```
hive_context.sql("select count(*) from ldg_sales").first()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

convert dataframe to rdd so you can run map task on it to just extract row values like -

```
df = hive_context.sql("select count(*) as cnt from ldg_sales")
count = df.rdd.map(lambda _ : _.cnt).collect()[0]
```